# Grabbing the text from HTML source code of URL using Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, rubygems

I've read a couple of articles and posts on stackoverflow surrounding this topic. I apologize if I am repeating someone else's post on stack. Is there a way to iterate through the HTML source code of a given URL and return the text of a header tag?

Example:

```
<h2 class='title'>
<a href="/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem">Step-by-Step Guide to Building Your First Ruby Gem</a>
</h2>
```

The code looks for the

tag and returns Step-by-Step Guide to Building Your First Ruby Gem. I know there's the Nokogiri gem that searches for nodes in a xpath:

```
doc.xpath('//h3/a').each do |link|
puts link.content
end
```

Is there one where I could potentially do

```
doc.html('h1').each do |tag| puts link.content end
```

I hope it makes sense...any insight of direction to a resource will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri has both XPath and CSS accessors, so you can do

```
doc.css('h1 > a').each do |tag| puts link.content end
```

if you don't like XPath. (Or just `'h1'` - I am not 100% sure if you want the text of links in headers, or headers themselves).

Comment: Nice! thanks for responding this fast Amadan. I guess I would want the text of the headers themselves.